# Ubuntu efi has the same UUID as Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a problem booting my PC.
Windows does have the same efi uuid as ubuntu, this should not be the case

For better readability: http://dpaste.com/1ECV55T

```
grischa@fianna:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v

[sudo] Passwort für grischa: 
BootCurrent: 000A
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0006,0001,0005,0009,0000,0002,0008,000A,0003
Boot0000* neon  HD(1,GPT,85d850da-ed40-4810-bb64-94725f6d1942,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\neon\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.C.r.u.c.i.a.l._.C.T.5.2.5.M.X.3.0.0.S.S.D.1....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . .7.1.3.0.5.1.E.7.2.B.6.1......AMBOAMNO........o.W.D.C. .W.D.1.0.E.Z.E.X.-.0.8.M.2.N.A.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.M.W.3.C.0.F.9.7.3.0.5.5......AMBOAMNO........o.S.a.n.D.i.s.k. .S.D.S.S.D.A.1.2.0.G....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.5.1.7.1.3.0.0.4.9.5.4.8. . . . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot0002* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  VenMedia(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012)AMBO
Boot0003  debian    HD(1,GPT,72e2139a-f60e-445e-8483-3fa2db2b60b8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,302c94da-ecca-4e65-9694-cc277ecc85cf,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.H.L.-.D.T.-.S.T. .D.V.D.R.A.M. .G.H.2.4.N.S.B.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.J.K.D.G.D.A.2.6.3.1. .6. . . . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,302c94da-ecca-4e65-9694-cc277ecc85cf,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
Boot0008* UEFI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSB0    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(2,65535,0)/CDROM(1,0x95b,0x2086c2)AMBO
Boot0009* USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........w.V.e.r.b.a.t.i.m.S.T.O.R.E. .N. .G.O. .1...0.0....................A.............................D..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.V.e.r.b.a.t.i.m.S.T.O.R.E. .N. .G.O. .1...0.0......AMBO
Boot000A* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO 1.00 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x15,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(4,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x0,0x2a5894,0x2000)AMBO
grischa@fianna:~$
```

Comment: they both boot from the same partition ( the EFI SystemPartition)

Comment: The EFI System Partition (ESP) is often shared by all the OSes installed on the computer. This is normal. If you'd intended to dedicate a separate ESP to Ubuntu, then you may have run into [this bug,](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379) which prevents this from working at install time. You can juggle the ESP post-installation by moving files, editing `/etc/fstab`, and using `efibootmgr` to change the Ubuntu entry, but unless you're experiencing a specific problem that this would overcome, the effort of doing so is likely greater than the benefit.